# facebook-c#-sdk FacebookUriMapper

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm tring to follow the [Configuring tutorial](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/config/) of the Facebook SDK for .NET.

But when I add the `RootFrame.UriMapper = new FacebookUriMapper();` line of code the `NavigationService` seems stop to work.

The app start's fine but the command `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/LoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));` inserted in a Button on init app page don't work. Other commands on same button like a `MessageBox.Show` works fine.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `FacebookUriMapper` in the Facebook.Client SDK has a bug. When looking via debugger, it doesn't redirect to the target page, but switches back to the default `RedirectUri` in `Facebook.xml`. Clone the repository in your computer, open the WP8 solution, restore required `Nuget` packages. Now, open `FacebookUriMapper.cs` file, modify the last `else` block to return `uri`. Build and use this as your referenced assembly. `NavigationService` works absolutely fine  after this.

Comment: Please mark as answer if found appropriate. You can build the `DLL`s yourself or PM me for pre-built `DLL`s