# NavigationService.Navigate neither navigates nor throws any exception

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a NavigationService.Navigate() call inside,

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    if (!IsoStoreSettings.ContainsKey("accesstoken") || !(IsoStoreSettings.ReadKey<DateTime>("tokenexpiry") > DateTime.Now))
    {
      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/signin.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't navigate to `signin.xaml`. But, the OnNavigatedTo() event is getting called twice. What am I doing wrong? I also added `Facebook SDK` to the project.

I also have `RootFrame.UriMapper = new FacebookUriMapper();` in `App.xaml.cs`

**Update**
This has something to do with the version of `Facebook` and `Facebook.Client` that I used. There are some incompatibilities between latest alpha packages.

Comment: This is a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284938/facebook-c-sdk-facebookurimapper) also has navigation issues due to facebook SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `FacebookUriMapper` in the [Facebook.Client](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk) SDK has a bug. When looking via debugger, it doesn't redirect to the target page, but switches back to the default `RedirectUri` in `Facebook.xml`. Clone the repository in your computer, open the WP8 solution, restore required `Nuget` packages. Now, open `FacebookUriMapper.cs` file, modify the last `else` block to return `uri`. Build and use this as your referenced assembly. `NavigationService` works absolutely fine  after this.

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone 8.1 does not support

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/signin.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

instead of this you can use

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(signin));
```

this method will navigate to signin page

Comment: Isnt this for Windows Store apps? Mine is an SL

Comment: for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055786/difference-between-windows-phone-silverlight-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-developme

Comment: @KarthikNishanth does your signin  is in any folder?

Comment: Its in root directory

Comment: in root directory, is there any folder for your view "signin" page

Comment: IF no try by  keeping a @ character in front of your string  @"/signin.xaml" else if any folder is there try to invoke page by its folder name "View/Page1.xaml"

Comment: That might not be the reason. [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284938/facebook-c-sdk-facebookurimapper) also has navigation issues due to facebook SDK